# Count of Same Objects in Two Sequences

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I'm having a real hard time trying to learn Python 3 and right now I'm struggling with this one exercise.

I have to write a function that takes two arguments:

1) A string which is a DNA sequence.

2) A string of the same length as argument one (also a DNA sequence)

The function must return a float (the proportion of bases that are the same in two DNA sequences).

So, i know i have to write a function that will return something like this:

```
seq_similarity("ATGC","AGTT")
```

should return

```
0.75
```

I've only come this far and now I'm stuck even before I started:

```
def sequence_similarity(seq1,seq2):
    seq1="AGTC"
    seq2="AGTT"
```

Can you help me get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` and give it a condition:

```
sum(x==y for (x,y) in zip(seq1, seq2))
```

This says 3 for your two strings.

So then divide by the length:

```
sum(x==y for (x,y) in zip(seq1, seq2))/len(seq1)
```

Watch out for integers if using 2.x:

```
sum(x==y for (x,y) in zip(seq1, seq2))/float(len(seq1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me the most because I was able to see WHY I'm having such a hard time with this as it helped me to see which parts of my book I should reread.

Comment: Practise the list comprehension things and some of the built in functions - you'll get a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin

```
  from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```